# Pyrogram, How to send /start with params

Tags: python, pyrogram

I have url https://t.me/Bot_name?start=mc_dSs8EMrECY1Jvwk
How can I follow this link using Program. Or how to send a telegram message to the bot /start with param mc_dSs8EMrECY1Jvwk

I tried using
`client.join_chat(url)`
the telegram server gives an invalid username error.
also try create inlinebutton with url and clicked on it, but nothing happens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kind of an hacky solution, but probably the only thing you could do is just parsing the URL and extracting the `start` GET argument. Then you can use the `messages.startBot` (https://docs.pyrogram.org/telegram/functions/messages/start-bot) method to send `/start <startarg>` to your bot.

Example:

```py
from pyrogram.raw import functions
from urllib.parse import urlparse, parse_qs

def parse_url(url: str):
    parsed = urlparse(url)
    return parsed.path[1:], parse_qs(parsed.query)['start']

username, start_param = parse_url(my_url)

client.invoke(
    functions.messages.StartBot(
        bot=client.resolve_peer(username),
        start_param=start_param
    )
)
```